# jQuery: Persisting form values before serialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

I am using jQuery serialize() function to collect data in a form and submit to server using jQuery Ajax "post" method, like this: `var params = jQuery('#mainContent form').serialize();`.
The strange thing I saw is the serialized data from my form contains old data. It means, all of my changes in form (input to text-field, select on combo-box) is not stored to DOM, so when jQuery call `serialize()`, it collect the old data which appeared before I change the form. I tried to inspect to each element in that form and call `.val()`, it still showed the old values.
So how can I persist all my changes to form, that the `serialize()` method can build the string with newest data I entered?
Here is my snippet code, I called `serialize()` inside submit handler

```
jQuery('.myFormDiv input.submit').click(function() {  
    // Do something  
    // Collect data in form  
    var params = jQuery('#mainContent form').serialize();  
    // Submit to server  
    jQuery.post(url, params, successHandler);  
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you upload your code (or a simplified version) to jsfiddle?

Comment: do you call `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 2):

When are you calling serialize? it should be $('form').submit( [here] ); It sounds like it's being called on page load, before you enter values into the fields, then being used after.

EDIT:

using the [submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of on click will catch someone hitting enter in a text field.

```
jQuery('#mainContent form').submit(function() {  
  // Collect data in form  
  var params = jQuery(this).serialize();  
  // Submit to server  
  jQuery.post(url, params, successHandler);  
}
```

*the above code assume url is define and successHandler is a function.

Comment: While it is good to use the submit event of the form rather than the click event of the submit button, it's unlikely to have any effect on the values in the serialised form—not much should happen between clicking the submit button and the form being submitted. Though it will ensure that the OP isn't submitting the wrong form from the button given the selectors are different.

Comment: @RobG Indeed. As I stated it sounds like serialize is being called on page load or some point before. Just giving a full example of how I mentioned to do it.